# curl Doesn't get file but firefox and any browsers could get

Tags: bash, jenkins, curl, jar

I want to create a Jenkins slave as a docker. so I use this Github [link](https://github.com/diodonfrost/docker-jenkins-slave/blob/master/ubuntu-18.04-jenkins-slave/Dockerfile.ubuntu-18.04) to create a Ubuntu Jenkins slave.

In this Dockerfile there is a section that use curl to get a jar file.

```
curl --create-dirs -sSLo /usr/share/jenkins/slave.jar https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/4.0/remoting-4.0.jar
```

When I want to curl a jar file with curl, didn't work but by any browsers, I could download the jar file.

Why curl bash command doesn't work?

Comment: Add curl's error message to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Make sure you have write permissions in the /usr/share/jenkins directory.

Comment: yeh in docker permission is as root 
the error is curl: (7) Failed to connect to repo.jenkins-ci.org port 443: Connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy in your web browser ?, if so, just:

```
export http_proxy=http://ip:port
export https_proxy=http://ip:port
```